# Range of the sum of two random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X,Y:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be two independent discrete random variables with range $R_{X}=\{x_{j}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ and $R_{Y}=\{y_{i}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$.

Is it then true that the sum $X+Y$ has range $R_{X}+R_{Y}$? The reason that I'm asking this question is because my textbook gives an example where $X$ and $Y$ both have range $\{1,2,...,n\}$, and then state that the range of $X+Y$ is $\{2,3,...,n\}$. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left\lbrace 1, 2, ...,n\right\rbrace + \left\lbrace 1, 2, ...,n\right\rbrace = \left\lbrace 2, 3, ...,2n\right\rbrace$$

Comment: Oh, its addition of sets..... -.- So, is it then wrong to type that $X+Y$ has range $R_{X}+R_{Y}$ if the ranges of $X$ and $Y$ are given by sequences as above, or?